# Automate Git clone from Private repo using SSH

Tags: bash, github, ssh

I have been writing bash script to clone private Github repo using SSH.
Steps need to be followed -

1. Generate SSH key using ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your email".
2. Copy the output of cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
3. Store it within - https://github.com/settings/keys

How do I automate step 3 in bash script.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You would still need to auth to github - is this just for yourself or everyone?

Comment: This is for everyone having access to that private repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the [GitHub API POST /user/keys](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/keys/#create-a-public-ssh-key-for-the-authenticated-user) to add a public SSH key to the authenticated user's GitHub account.

It requires that you are authenticated via Basic Auth, or OAuth with at least write:public_key scope.

So your script must take as parameter.

Result: [example](https://gist.github.com/yin/d1ffd327f37dc584ec2f202848dc5db0)

```
# Add a SSH-Key (type "user:passwd ^D"), output: JSON object, or JSON error
curl -X POST -u <user[:passwd]> https://api.github.com/user/keys \
  --data "{\"title\": \"<title>\", \"key\": \"$(cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)\"}"
```

([other example here](https://gist.github.com/pconwell/a404a8a156a1f8cc2a3bd01340538c95))

Comment: Great thanks! Is there any way where I can avoid entering the password in the script?

Comment: @snn Yes, with an OAuth token: https://help.github.com/en/github/extending-github/git-automation-with-oauth-tokens

Comment: Got it. Thank you